# Cannot set text to input field with PCA Predict

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I'm create automatic test.

And I have a huge problem with fields with pca predict with autocomplete - I have no idea how to write test to set some address.

[image]

After set some value:

[image]

I don't know what I should do - focus on autocomplete or set some text for every single field? I mean (for example) Address field.

```
<input type="text" id="address.street" name="address.street" value placeholder="Address" class="error-field" autocomplete="off">
```

I tried:

1.

```html
    def driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    String baseUrl = "https://logicvapes.us/customer/account/create"
    
    selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl)
    
    selenium.type("id=billing_form.street", "Clifford Dr")
    selenium.sendKeys("id=billing_form.street", "${KEY_ENTER}")
```

2.

```html
    WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('TestObject'), Keys.chord('Clifford Dr',Keys.TAB))
```

Comment: The URL is not working in other network and its hard to analyze where the problem. Update you question with sufficient HTML code, UI screenshot and code snippet tried by you.

Comment: Done, can you look at my issue now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Katalon Studio you could do this:

```
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('TestObject'), 'Clifford Dr')
WebUI.delay(1)
WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('TestObject'), Keys.chord(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER))
```

It will simulate entering the text, dropdown list will show up, then keybord arrow down and enter are pressed.

Be sure to import

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys
```